# How to Generate INVOKE-POLYMORPHIC opcodes in Dalvik

Tags: android, dalvik, dex

I'm in the process of Developing a Dalvik Bytecode interpreter for 16-bit boards. I have implemented and tested translation operations for most opcodes but have been unable to test some others as I have not been able to figure out how to write the Java code that generates them. In particular I've been unable to generate the "invoke-polymorphic" and "invoke-custom" opcodes. (as well as their equivalents in Dalvik 35, I am developing with Dalvik 38 in mind) I've tried simply running a method inside a class which overrides a superclass method like so:

```
SuperClass x = new SubClass();
x.mymethod();
```

Which is the textbook simple example of polymorphism but it just seems to generate regular "invoke-direct" opcodes.

Additionally, I'm not altogether clear on what is meant by a "method handle" or "call site" and why they are needed for polymorphic invocation. (The Dalvik Documentation does not seem to elaborate very much on this).

Answer (score 6):

## invoke-polymorphic

"Polymorphism" is a pretty vague term. Method overriding or overloading for instance is ofter referred as polymorphism. In the case of the "invoke-polymorphic" instruction, the term refers to so called "signature polymorphic" methods.

Signature polymorphic methods may accept any kind and count of arguments.
From java source perspective, they look and behave like any method with one vararg `Object...` parameter, but they differ on the bytecode-level. While varargs methods are invoked by passing an array with all additional parameters, this is not necessary for "invoke-polymorphic" methods. Polymorphic methods can be invoked with **any** descriptor. Neither creating an array of parameters nor boxing arguments of primitive types is necessary.

The only signature polymorphic methods that exist are [MethodHandle#invoke(Object...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.html#invoke-java.lang.Object...-) and [MethodHandle#invokeExact(Object...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.html#invokeExact-java.lang.Object...-) (see [JvmSpec §2.9.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se11/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.9.3)).

So here's code that produces a "invoke-polymorphic" instructions:

```
void foo(MethodHandle handle) throws Throwable {
    handle.invoke(10, 20);
    handle.invokeExact("foo", "bar");
}
```

Let's compile it, run `dx` and view it with `baksmali`:

```
const/16 v0, 0xa
const/16 v1, 0x14
invoke-polymorphic {p1, v0, v1}, Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;->invoke([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;, (II)V

const-string v0, "foo"
const-string v1, "bar"
invoke-polymorphic {p1, v0, v1}, Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;->invokeExact([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;, (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

## invoke-custom

The "invoke-custom" instruction is dalvik's equivalent of the JVM's [invokedynamic](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se11/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.invokedynamic) instruction.

Dynamic invokes do not invoke one statically known method. They provide a "bootstrap method" that is used to resolve a CallSite. A CallSite is basically a wrapper around a [MethodHandle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.html) that may or may not be mutable. Once the CallSite of a "invokedynamic" instruction has been resolved, its stored by the JVM and is from now on invoked when ever the instruction is executed. This whole process was described in more detail in the [JVM Spec 10 §6.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se10/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.invokedynamic).

Bootstrap methods are just regular java methods that return a CallSite and must have at least three parameters.

- The first parameter is a [Lookup](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.Lookup.html) instance that has access to all classes/fields/methods that can be accessed from the method that contains the invokedynamic instruction.
- The second parameter is often called "name". It is an arbitrary String that is defined by the invokedynamic instruction.
- The third parameter is a MethodType. The returned CallSite must exactly match this type. This can be achieve through the [MethodHandle#asType](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.html#asType-java.lang.invoke.MethodType-) method.
- Further arguments can be passed. They must be constant values stored within the invokedynamic instructions.

Note: Do not expected the bootstrap method to exactly match the signature described above. A parameter can for instance be of type Object. It is also possible replace some arguments against one vararg parameter.

The "invokedynamic" instruction was introduced with the jvm 7 to support dynamic languages but was not used by the java language itself. The instruction was first used in java 8 to compile lambdas. Since java 9 string concatenations are implemented with a "invokedynamic" call.

So here's example code that produces an invoke dynamic instruction:

```
Supplier<String> someLambda = () -> "foo";
```

After running `javac`, `dx` and `baksmali` we'll see get following instructions:

```
invoke-custom {}, call_site_0("get", ()Ljava/util/function/Supplier;, ()Ljava/lang/Object;, invoke-static@LTest;->lambda$foo$0()Ljava/lang/String;, ()Ljava/lang/String;)@Ljava/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory;->metafactory(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite;

.method private static synthetic lambda$foo$0()Ljava/lang/String;
    const-string v0, "foo"
    return-object v0
.end method
```

Let's have a closer look at how java 9 compiles String concatenations.
Here's our example code:

```
String foo(Object a, Object b) {
    return "a = " + a + ", b = " + b;
}
```

And the resulting instruction:

```
invoke-custom {p1, p2}, call_site_0("makeConcatWithConstants", (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;, "a = \u0001, b = \u0001")@Ljava/lang/invoke/StringConcatFactory;->makeConcatWithConstants(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite;
```

First of all we've got `{p1, p2}`. These two registers are the values that get passed as arguments to the CallSite once it gets invoked.

Then we've got the `call_site_0(...)` block. `call_site_0` is the name of this callsite that can be used to differentiate between otherwise identical callsites. The Block stores some informations passed as arguments to the bootstrap method.

- The first value ("makeConcatWithConstants") is the arbitrary String that is passed as second parameter to the bootstrap method.
- The second value is a MethodType constant. It is passed as third argument to the bootstrap method and matches exactly the type of the returned CallSite. In this case we've got a method that accepts two objects (p1 and p2) and returns a String (the concatenated String).
- All following values are additional constant arguments that are passed to the bootstrap method. In this case it's only one string that is a pattern for the final concatenated string.

The last thing (starting at the '@' symbol) is the reference to the bootstrap method.